# Blender Geometry Node : Mesh Boolean isn't working on instances

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, instances

When I try if I use individual ico-spheres (individually transformed) as inputs for the the boolean works just fine, however if I use instances on points the output disappears!
Trying to resolve this for hours now, but can't seem to understand why it's not working.
Could anyone please help?

[image: Mesh Boolean isn't working on instances]

[image: Blender 4 vs Blender 3.5 behavior]

Comment: What happens if you add a Realise Instances node after the Instance on Points one?

Comment: It's not working, it looks the same!
I should have mentioned that it's working in 3.6, what I am using in 4.0.
Is there any change in Blender 4's GN?

Comment: perhaps check the "self intersection" check box. (also, it makes sense for it nit to work with instances (unless they are within a single instance ‍♂️))

Comment: Looks like it was a bug in the Blender 4 Beta 7 Nov. I installed the release candidate Blender 4 (12.11) and now it works fine. No realize instance is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug in the Blender 4 Beta 7 Nov.
I installed the release candidate Blender 4 (12.11) and now it works fine.
No **realize instance** is needed.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine here with <kbd>Realise Instances</kbd> added in Blender 4.00 beta:

version: 4.0.0 Beta, branch: blender-v4.0-release, commit date: 2023-11-07 21:30, hash: 7f89063161cf, type: release
build date: 2023-11-08, 02:04:51

[image]

The only difference I can see is that your version only has one Mesh input on the <kbd>Mesh Boolean</kbd> node and I see an <kbd>I</kbd> in the boolean header bar which says "Instances in input geometry are ignored" when you hover over it if I leave the Realise Instances node out!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and taking time to try it out.
I have added the difference between V4 Beta and V3.5 GN.
The V3.5 one is the intended one and doesn't need realize instances node.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not seeing the same result as you in 3.5.1. The result here is exactly the same as in 4.0 including the two Boolean inputs and Info icon as shown in my answer above. Can't really help any further as we're seeing different results.

Comment: My mistake, I meant 3.6.5 (latest stable)
When I open the same file in 4.0 beta it adds the realizes nodes and the results don't intersect like the 3.6.5

Comment: Ok. I agree about 4.0 adding the Realise instances node automatically if you save in 3.65 and then open in 4.0 and the reason I was seeing the extra boolean mesh input and the info warning was because I had the node set to Difference not Intersect.  However I still have to manually add the Realise Instances node in 3.65 before I can see anything which is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Realize instances before boolean operation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.

Comment: It's not working, it looks the same! if I increase the instances value it crashes Blender.
I should have mentioned that it's working in 3.6, what I am using in 4.0.
Is there any change in Blender 4's GN?